# Different Views for different users in android

Tags: android

I am beginner in android and planning to build an app which will have different views based user type. Say when user A signs up, based on his ID, he will get to see a view which will be different from the view which user B sees (when he signs up using his id). Could someone please guide how to achieve this. The users will be authenticated from database based on category. For each category type I want to have a different view and subsequent screens. Pointers to relevant links, tutorials will be helpful.

My Second question: User A completes his activity and presses a button, user B should get the notification (say by some color change) of the same. I mean the status updates from different users of their activity completion should be updated and be seen by everyone at runtime.

My sincere apologies if someone sees this questions as a basic level one but I have searched the web and didn't find any relevant links(may be not searching right way).

Any sort of guidance would be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: **Say when user A signs up, based on his ID, he will get to see a view which will be different from the view which user B sees (when he signs up using his id).** manage users based on there login use switch case or something else to go through different user screen you want to handle. Whats there to search here ? its just a simple thing

Comment: Thanks. Looks simple now.

Comment: for your second question **User A completes his activity and presses a button, user B should get the notification (say by some color change) of the same. I mean the status updates from different users of their activity completion should be updated and be seen by everyone at runtime.** you will need to have a call between the button pressed event which will trigger user B about the event done by user A activity.May be a web service / broadcastreceiver / some kind of source code which can pass the information from one device to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the category of the user from the database and set the activity upon the category or make the views `visible` or `gone` based on the category. I can't understand the second question though.

Comment: Thanks Naresh. My 2nd question is say there are 3 levels to be completed by 3 different users.  User A needs to complete level 1 and once he finishes it, then only B can start with level 2. So when A presses complete button for level 1, the same should be updated in Database and broadcast to each user/device about completion of level 1(may be changing color in status field). So now B on his device gets to know that level 1 is completed (by seeing the status) and he can start working on level 2. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You must use `BroadcastReceiver` for this. Probably you must look for some good tutorials to get notifications using that. For this you need server side implementation as well.